# TensorFlow 2.0 Layer with None type shape Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

The function below I am attempting to call in a `tf.keras.layers.Lambda()` in adherence to TF 2.0. The `inputs` and `outputs` tensors will be two images of the same dimension with 3 color channels. My goal is to extract a mask from the `outputs` tensor, apply it to the `inputs` tensor, then return the resulting tensor. The motivation for flattening the tensors is due to the limitations of the `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update()` function. When I construct the model, it fails to initialize `updates` since `indices.shape[0]` is a `None` value. If I call this layer outside the model with two `tf.constant()` tensors to initialize `x`, it runs perfectly fine in eager execution (since the `x` tensors have defined values). Unfortunately when I call this function with `tf.keras.layers.Lambda()` I recieve the following error:

`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'NoneType'`

```
@tf.function
def applyMask(x):
  # Extract Tensors
  inputs = x[0]
  outputs = x[1]

  # Flatten the Outputs Tensor and Extract Mask Indices 
  outputs = tf.reshape(outputs,(tf.size(outputs),))
  indices = tf.where(outputs==1.)
  indices = tf.cast(indices, tf.int32)

  # Construct Updates Tensor from Mask Indices
  updates = tf.constant([1.]*indices.shape[0])

  # Flatten Input Tensor and Apply Mask
  out_dim = inputs.shape
  inputs = tf.reshape(inputs,(tf.size(inputs),))
  tensor = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(inputs, indices, updates)

  # Reconstruct Input Into Tensor
  tensor = tf.reshape(tensor, out_dim)
  return tensor
```

Comment: So all you need to do is get where output==1 and set those indices to 1 in the inputs?

Comment: yep, simple as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't need to be this complex. Simply do,

```
inp1 = Input(shape=(None, None, 3)) # Inputs
inp2 = Input(shape=(None, None, 3)) # Outputs

out = Lambda(lambda x: tf.where(tf.equal(x[1], 1), x[1], x[0]))([inp1, inp2])
```

And you can even have `height` and `width` `None` and as long as parallel samples passed to `inp1` and `inp2` are exactly the same (shape-wise), `tf.where` will work fine.